# How to make Canvas fulfilled the page

Tags: javascript

How I can make Canvas which fulfilled the visible part of page. Everything what I tried give me bigger canvas with scrollbars, or significantly smaller.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p></p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<script>
canvasInit();


function canvasInit() {
    var dimension = [document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight];
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    c.width = dimension[0];
    c.height = dimension[1];
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Page in browser]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

```
c.width = window.innerWidth * 2;
c.height = window.innerHeight * 2;
c.style.width = `${window.innerWidth}px`;
c.style.height = `${window.innerHeight}px`;
```

Comment: Hello, everything is the same, just the object inside the canvas becomes smaller.

Comment: Also make sure your body has styles margin:0; padding:0

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this.

set the width like this.

```
width = window. innerWidth; canvas. height = window. innerHeight;
```

You could even change it in your javascript

```
var canvasW     = 640;
var canvasH     = 480;
```

Even better, you can just put this in your canvasinit() function.

```
canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth; //document.width is obsolete
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight; //document.height is obsolete
canvasW = canvas.width;
canvasH = canvas.height;
```

Comment: When i did it I saw really weird behavior. I add screenshot how it looks in main post.